# Virtual Assistant Deployment Script cannot deploy LUIS or Knowledgebase

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I've been using the Virtual Assistant Template to try and create the resources required for my bot however I have been running into some issues. The deployment script seems to run fine until it gets to the sections where it generates the LUIS apps and the QnA Knowledgebases. Here's the issues I get at these sections;

```
> Deploying cognitive models ...
> Initializing dispatch model ...
> Parsing General LU file ...
> Deploying General LUIS app ...
! Could not deploy LUIS model. Review the log for more information.
! Log: C:\Users\mark.weir02\source\repos\Bari\Bari\Bari\Deployment\Scripts\..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt
> Setting LUIS subscription key ...
! Could not create LUIS app. Skipping dispatch add.
> Parsing Chitchat LU file ...
> Deploying Chitchat QnA kb ...
2
> Retrying ...
1
> Retrying ...
0
> Retrying ...
-1
! Unable to create QnA KB.
! Could not deploy knowledgebase. Review the log for more information.
! Log: C:\Users\mark.weir02\source\repos\Bari\Bari\Bari\Deployment\Scripts\..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt
! Could not create knowledgebase. Skipping dispatch add.
```

In the deploy_cogntivie_models_log.txt file that is generated there is no information on the errors, the file is just blank which is making it hard to troubleshoot the issue. Here's the details I've been providing to the script;

```
Bot Name - UK-Bari (I've tried to use names of non-existing resource groups, existing groups and deleted groups)
Azure Resource Group Location - westeurope
Password for MSA app registration : <Password that meets requirements>
LUIS Authoring Region: westeurope
LUIS Authoring Key: <The Primary Key for my Starter Key>
```

When I log into LUIS I am getting the following error message, however I am not sure if it is related;
[image]

All other aspects of the script seem to work and publish to Azure. Is there a way to fix this issue or am I better to manually create the LUIS, QnA and Dispatch models and then add them into my code?

Comment: My assumption, is that that error does have something to do with it. Have you migrated your LUIS authoring resources?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-authoring    

The other thing you could try, would be to try and run the commands (dispatch, etc) that are ran from within deploy_cognitive_models.ps1. To make sure each one works.